# how to write this not Exists sql

Tags: sql, oracle

features is a primary table
feature_groups is a join table joining features and groups
group_orgs another join table joining groups and orgs

in simplicity

```
features
--------
feature_id
name

feature_groups
----------
feature_id
group_id

group_orgs
---------
group_id
org_id
```

I want to find all features that exist in feature_groups whose group_id NOT exist in group_orgs.  The following seems to work, but just wondering if this is the best way to do it.

```
select f.feature_id
from   features f 
       left join feature_groups fg
       on f.feature_id = fg.feature_id
where  fg.feature_id is not null
and    not exists
           ( select group_id
             from   group_orgs gor
             where  fg.group_id = gor.group_id )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it gives you the right results and isn't *too* slow then it's probably good enough, however I would note that your `LEFT JOIN WHERE x IS NOT NULL` is effectively an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select f.feature_id
from   features f 
       inner join feature_groups fg
       on f.feature_id = fg.feature_id
and    not exists
           ( select group_id
             from   group_orgs gor
             where  fg.group_id = gor.group_id )
```

Comment: yes, my intention was to do an inner join.  My ansi sql is a little rusty.  thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
SELECT f.feature_id
FROM   features f
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT 'X'
  FROM   feature_groups fg
  WHERE  f.feature_id = fg.feature_id
  AND    NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM   group_orgs gor
    WHERE  fg.group_id = gor.group_id
  )
);
```

Using a join between `features` and `feature_groups` can produce duplicate results if there is a one-many relationship. Using `EXISTS` will only return a single row whereas a one-many join will return duplicate rows.

Another options is to use `IN` and `NOT IN` instead of `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: It's an option, but it's worse than the original. Normally you should prefer joins over subqueries. And especially try to avoid nested subqueries.